# paging xml data

Tags: php, jquery, xml, paging

how do i implement paging on xml data which is being called through php. i've been trying various jquery pagination on the xml file with no luck.

html/php code reading the xml data:

```
<div id="display">
        <?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set("display_errors", 1);

            $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
            if(!file_exists('test.xml')){
              echo "Sorry this file does not exists!";
              exit();
            } else {
                $xmldoc->load('test.xml', LIBXML_NOBLANKS);

               // Load up the XSL file
                $xslDoc = new DomDocument;
                $xslDoc->load("test.xsl");
                $xsl = new XSLTProcessor;
                $xsl->importStyleSheet($xslDoc);

                // apply the transformation
                echo $xsl->transformToXml($xmldoc);
            } 
         ?>
    </div>
```

script [[one example](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-pagination)]:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="paginator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){ $("#display").pagination(); });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide what's going to be on separate pages. That's entirely dependent on the content of the xml file. I don't think you'll find a great general solution.

Comment: separate pages as in? please elaborate. do you mean to say that the pagination script has to be either put on the php page or the xsl?

Comment: No. I mean that if you're going to break anything into separate pages, you need to decide what goes on each page. If your xml data is a bunch of address records, you might want 25 on a page. If your xml is a single article, you need to decide where you're going to split it.

Comment: it's records displaying english text and it's translation. how do i make the xml file or the paging show 10 records per page?

Comment: ahh, i get now what you mean. thanks for the pointer, anyway.